# Remove iCloud Photos from Mac only?

Tags: icloud, photos

I want to remove the photo library from my mac as it is taking up 25.4GB of space but I want to keep all of the photos on the iCloud so they are accessible from my other devices.

I saw in the settings that there is a Disable and Delete button but I am under the assumption that it will remove all the images from my iCloud too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can turn off iCloud Photo Library on your Mac by following the steps in this Apple support doc: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204570.  I always backup my photos first, just in case I make a mistake.  If this is an option for you then I recommend doing the backup before you make any changes.

- On your Mac, go to `System Preferences > iCloud > Options` next to *Photos*
- Deselect `iCloud Photo Library`

This will stop photos from syncing to your Mac.  As you've seen, **do not** select *Disable and Delete* from this same menu as it will delete your photos from every device.

Comment: Once I've done that am I safe to delete the existing photos from my Mac?